# Finding a sequence with some summation properties $\sum\binom{n}{k}a_k=\binom{2n}{n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, algebra-precalculus, binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem

I was wondering if there exists a nontrivial sequence of numbers $a_{k}$ with the following property:

$$\sum_{k=0}^{N}\binom{n}{k}a_{k}=\binom{2n}{n},$$

where the integer $N=\lfloor\tfrac12n\rfloor$ is $\tfrac12n$ when $n$ is even, and $\tfrac12(n-1)$ when $n$ is odd, and take $n>0$.

By a nontrivial sequence I mean one in which no terms are zero, or if that cannot be done, not all terms but one are zero (the obvious solution).

I guessed that they might be related to Catalan numbers but I'm really not so familiar with their properties and wasn't sure of the best way to approach the question, whether through generating functions or just a clever substitution or something else.

This is only done out of curiosity, so I would consider a reference totally fine, without a proof, but of course understanding why is always great.

Comment: $m=\lfloor\tfrac12n\rfloor$ must be less than $n$ when $n>0$.

Comment: Note that $a_k$ must to depends on $n$, because for $n=0$ we have $\binom 00 a_0=\binom 00$ from which $a_0=1$ while for $n=1$ we have $\binom 10 a_0=\binom 21$ which gives $a_0=2$.

Comment: Since the summation limit depends on $n,$ I expect the terms $a_k$ will also depend on $n$ as well. Thanks, I will edit the question to make that clearer.

Comment: As pointed out by Alex R., you may take $a_{n0}=\frac 1n\binom{2n}n$ and $a_{nk}=0$ for $k>0$.

Comment: Ok, I'll edit this slightly to avoid the trivial solution and restrict the range of the question a little bit.

Comment: I guess we may make use of the identity $\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}^2 = \binom{2n}{n}$ together with the symmetry $\binom{n}{k} = \binom{n}{n-k}$. So, we may set $$a_{n,k} = \begin{cases} 2\binom{n}{k}, & \text{if $k<n/2$};\\ \binom{n}{k}, & \text{if $k=n/2$}.\end{cases} $$

Comment: the answer by @SangchulLee is probably the most "natural" (+1).  OTOH, if you restrict yourself to even $n$, then you can find a sequence that doesn't depend on $n$ because as $n = 0, 2, 4, ...$ the equation successively introduces just one new term $a_0, a_1, a_2, ...$ every time, so you can actually solve for it.